# autocomplete form and download page

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a page that automatically completes a form and downloads the result page, here is an example:

i have a page index.html with this code

```
<form method="post" action="result.php">
  Insert your email<br>
  <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

and the page result

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
echo 'your email is: ' . $email;
```

having said that, how do I create a test.php page that inserts something in the form, clicks submit and downloads the entire result page to a .txt file on my pc? 
more than the code I'd like to understand the logic behind it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to create files into the server and download it with [headers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        file_put_contents('file.txt', 'your email is: ' . $email);
        header('Content-Type: application/txt');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.txt');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        readfile("file.txt");
```

> #### file_put_contents() Parameters
>
> **filename** - Path to the file where to write the data.
>
> **data** - The data to write. Can be either a string, an array or a stream resource. If data is a stream resource, the remaining buffer of
>   that stream will be copied to the specified file. This is similar with
>   using stream_copy_to_stream(). You can also specify the data parameter
>   as a single dimension array. This is equivalent to
>   file_put_contents($filename, implode('', $array)).
>
> **flags** The value of flags can be any combination of the following flags, joined with the binary OR (|) operator.